# Chopping of java array list

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am trying to write Java code for the following problem.But I am not able to find out a optimized way to solve this .

I have an array list of time and consumption of coffee as follows. I want to calculate the consumption of coffee every hours and if there is no consumption for a particular hour the next hours first entry will be the total consumption for that hour.

For Example :

I have the following array list

```
Time        consumption of coffee
2:15                5 cups
2:30                6 cups
2:45                7 cups
3:05                2 cups
3:45                6 cups
5:05                1 cups
5:30                2 cups
7:15                1 cup
```

so I want to calculate what is the total consumption for hour 2 which will be in that case 18 cups from 2:00 to 3:00 .again for  3:00 to 4:00 it will be 8 cups. As there is no entry from 4:00 to 5:00 amount of consumption in that case should be amount of coffee consumed at 5:05 which is 1 cup.I want my result till 7 o'clock. As we don't have anything at 6:00 -7 :00 then it will be 1 cup which was value at 7:15.

So I want a final result of total consumption from 2:00 to 7:00 distributed every hour as array list as following object

```
obj1 = T<2:00,3:00,18>
obj2 = T<3:00,4:00,8>
obj3 = T<4:00,5:00,1>
obj4 = T<5:00,6:00,3>
obj5 = T<6:00,7:00,1>

finalList = <obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5>
```

I am not able to get how to chop the list in hourly way and look at the next value as well.

Comment: It might be easier to help if you post the code that you have.

Comment: What happens if (in your example) you had instead `3:45->6 cups; 5:55->8 cups; 7:15->1 cup`?  Would you end up counting 8 cups for `4:00-5:00` and also 8 cups for `5:00 to 6:00`?  That seems rather distorted.

Comment: So if there is no coffee in the current time range we go to the next interval?

Comment: Are we to assume every 15 minutes is a memory slot in your array list? If so just create a list and add a variable sum which would be a group of 4 values from the previous list in each slot.

Answer (score 0):

You completely lost me as to the logic of filling an empty hour with first value from the next hour. But I'll give it a shot anyways.

My approach assumes your input data is in chronological order from earlier to later.

Define a `CoffeeConsumption` class with two members, [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) and `Integer` for your two values.

Create a `Map`, perhaps a [`SortedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) such as `TreeMap`. The key is of type `Integer`, and represents the hour of the day from 0 to 23. The value is of type `Set`, perhaps a `SortedSet` such as `TreeSet` to store your custom objects defined above.

For each of you custom objects, grab its `LocalTime` and call [`getHour`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#getHour--). Use that hour number to find the matching key in the Map, retrieve the Set, and add your item.

To get totals, loop the Map, and loop each Set. To save the totals, create a new SortedMap with Integer as key for hour-of-day and Integer as value for the hour’s total number of cups consumed.

Note that there is no need to save explicitly the end-of-hour time as you showed in your Question. You can always calculate that value: call `LocalTime::plusHours( 1 )`.

To support that move-first-item-to-previous-hour-if-empty feature, follow the logic I just outlined in that hyphenated title. When adding a coffee object to the Map with no existing key yet put there for that hour, first subtract one from the hour and look in the Map for that subtracted number as key. If the subtracted key is not present in the Map, put it, create a fresh empty Set in which to deposit the coffee object that would otherwise have gone to its own hour. Caveat: This feature has a bad smell and suggests something is wrong with your design or the requirement is misunderstood.